# Find a sum of matching values of [a Python list] in a Pandas Dataframe cell?

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, sum

***Bottom line question:***

This is ugly, right? For a pandas dataframe:

**`happyBarFrame['Sunday'].apply(lambda x : x == [0]).value_counts()[0]`**

***Long version:*** I am trying to find the sum of "empty" values in a Pandas Dataframe. Empty is when the entry is [0] -- a list.

I guess the best solution is not to use a list [0] as a value in a dataframe cell. Assuming I am sticking with that, I'd like to understand why so many functions don't work, giving a "unhashable list" error?

Yes this is a homework assignment for a data science class. We scrape a webpage that presents bars and happy hours. I have built this dataframe, I was using lists of hours where the last entry in the list is when the happy hour ends. Ignoring a couple bugs in the data:
[image: DataFrame of happy hours by day of week]

I am coming to believe that storing lists inside a dataframe is not the best idea, because many functions I would expect to work tell me they can't hash as list:

`In [173]: happyBarFrame['Sunday'].value_counts()`

... skipping long error ...

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

**Question is: I have tried the following, among many other things. What's the best approach to count the cells by day that have a list with a single 0 (cell value = [0])?**

`happyBarFrame[happyBarFrame['Sunday'].isin([[0]])]` -- Doesn't work
`happyBarFrame[happyBarFrame['Sunday'].isin([0])]` -- Doesn't work

Both give `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

---

**`happyBarFrame['Sunday'].apply(lambda x : x == [0]).value_counts()[0]`**

**Does work but just feels wrong!** I can iterate through the days of the week, getting the count by day and then build the histogram I need to build. But there must be a better way, this seems really inefficient, true?

EDIT: Fixed a bug where need to count True, not False, in value_counts[0]

Comment: I have looked at several "similar" questions but can't find one that deals specifically with using Python lists as values in a dataframe, if there is a duplicate I'd be happy to delete this question thanks

Comment: And ultimately I am building a list of seven items, the sum for each day of the week of bars that have happy hours: `listOfSumsByDay.append(happyBarFrame['Sunday'].apply(lambda x : x == [0]).value_counts()[1])`

Comment: yeah lists in dataframe is not a very easy format to work with, if I were you I'd have separate columns for happyhour_start and happyhour_duration for each day, setting it `NaN` if there's no happy hour for that day

Comment: if you have to store arrays like this, you could use tuples instead of lists, at least these are hashable

Comment: As you've found, using lists in DataFrames often leads to problems.  You should think about restructuring your data into a "long" format, with just four columns: restaurant, link, day, and hour.  The happy hour for PF Chang's would then be a series of *rows*: Sunday/15, Sunday/16, Sunday/17, ..., Monday/15, Monday/16, etc.  You will find this format is often easier for many tasks that pandas lets you do.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for the overall / background info, and the suggestions on Pandas. The original DF structure is sort of hard-baked into the assignment but this is exactly the "real-world" advice I was looking for. maxymoo had a very specific improvement so I accepted that answer, thanks again for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to apply a function to every cell in a dataframe, you can use `applymap`; then to get the column sums, just call `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sunday": [[0],[0,1]], "Monday": [[0],[0]]})
df.applymap(lambda x: x == [0]).sum()

Monday    2
Sunday    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Oh very cool! I saw applymap but didn't follow up on it. Let me try this, you answered first, if it works and it the most clean answer I will accept soon thanks

Comment: That is pretty cool, I just have to cut the link column, the bar chart is really easy! Thanks `happyBarFrame.applymap(lambda x: x != [0]).sum().plot(kind='bar')`